# How can I access to /etc/network/interfaces in my sd card?

Tags: raspbian

I messed up info in /etc/network/interfaces , but I couldn't find it when I read sd card in my mac. How can I access to this folder ?

Answer (score 2):

First, get an add on that can allow your mac to read ext4 formatted files. Then you should be able to get into the folders.

Answer (score 1):

I could do that using fuse-ext2

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert SD card into mac
2. Have a look at `dmesg` to find the device file of the SD card
3. Mount the 2nd partition of the SD card somewhere
4. `cd` into that directory
5. `cd` into `etc/network/`
6. edit file `interfaces`
7. ???
8. profit